# How to create and manage a Twitter Bootstrap Modal with Ember.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I was able to get a nice bootstrap modal to show / hide properly and display a msg stored on the modal controller as demonstrated here:
[Ember Bootstrap Modal Example](http://jsfiddle.net/robcmills/78Pne/)

Relevant code {

```html
// context
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application"> 
  <div class="container">
    {{outlet}}
  </div>
  <div id="modal" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ariaLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    {{render "modal"}}
  </div>
</script>

// modal template
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="modal">
  <div class="modal-header"> 
    <h2>{{title}}</h2> 
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body"> 
    <h4>{{{msg}}}</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="span3 pull-right">
      <button 
        id="modalBtn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" style="vertical-align:bottom"
        {{bindAttr class=":btn :btn-large :btn-block isCorrect:btn-success:btn-danger" }} 
        {{action "callback"}}>
        {{btn}}
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

```js
// controllers
App.HomeController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['modal'],

  showModal: function(){
    var modCon = this.get('controllers.modal');

    if( modCon.get('isCorrect') ){ // some logic
      modCon.setProperties({
        title: 'Correct',
        msg: 'You get points',
        btn: 'Next'
      });
    }
    else{
      modCon.setProperties({
        title: 'Incorrect',
        msg: 'Please try again',
        btn: 'Close'
      });
    }
    $('#modal').modal(); // show
  }
});

App.ModalController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  isCorrect: true,
  title: 'modCon title',
  msg: 'modCon message',
  btn: 'modCon btn label',
  callback: function(){
     alert('modal controller caught action');
  }
});
```

I'm posting this here for two reasons:

1. Am I doing it right? With Ember it can be difficult to understand how the developers intended certain things to be accomplished.
2. If others can help improve / verify it's validity then it can serve as an example for those with the desire to implement Bootstrap modals in Ember.js

Comment: There is already a very good implementation of the twitter bootsrap modal (and other components) wrappers to play nicely with ember. Check this out: https://github.com/emberjs-addons/ember-bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Ember CLI users, here are some more recent approaches / link updates:

https://github.com/mattbeedle/ember-cli-bootstrap-modal-example

http://indexiatech.github.io/ember-components/#/overview

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at *Ember for Bootstrap*, it has a simple yet powerful ways to use Bootstrap modals in Ember:

Modal Demo: http://ember-addons.github.io/bootstrap-for-ember/#/show_components/modal

GitHub repo: https://github.com/bootstrap-for-ember/bootstrap-for-ember

Answer (score 1):

This it's another way to do what you want.

What I did was had a modal like this:

```
<!-- modal edit dialog -->
<div class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" id="editView">
        {{view MainApp.ModalContainerView elementId="modalContainerView"}}
</div>
```

Where "MainApp.ModalContainerView" its a [container view](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ContainerView.html). Then when I wanted to render/show any template for a model I did this :

```
        var containerView = Em.View.views['modalContainerView']; 
        if(containerView == undefined)
            return;
        var temp =  containerView.toArray(); 
        if(temp.length > 0)
            containerView.removeAllChildren();
        containerView.addObject(view);
```

Where the "view" its the view you want to show in the modal. Notice that I'm removing the last view that's in the "modalContainerView", in order to be sure that I not have any view in that container.

finally I only have to show the modal:

```
$('#editView').modal({
            show : true,
            keyboard : true,
            resizeToFit : true
});
```

I hope that this can help you.

Juanitos

Answer (score 0):

A lot of times, I use modal as separate template with its own route and controller because modals in my applications are very powerful and need to service several ajax calls.